# WP Elementor crashes when editing a page with a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, elementor

I have added a shortcode in a page on my WordPress site, my shortcode is correctly called :
[my_function]

I have added my function in the function.php correctly:

```
function myfunction () {
     require_once('way_to_a_file.php');
     echo $my_content;
}

add_shortcode('my_function', 'myfunction')
```

My code **works well as expected** but when I want to edit the page where I put my shortcode, Elementor crashes sending me to a generalist page for errors, without any precision

I have tried to change 'echo' by 'return' but it doesn't works, I have tried to put the php code directly in the shortcode widget (non functionning).

I don't have more idea and I don't find documentation on this.

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Why not share the error you are facing?

Comment: The error is a blank page when I open elementor editor on the page where i put the shortcode

Answer (score 1):

Using the shortcodes you should output data via return function, not echo. More information about that you can find here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/

To avoid unnecessary issues during Elementor you can change the code to check if the file exists before include it. Try code like below. Make sure also the file is correct and dosen't collide with any Elementor function.

```php
function myfunction () {
    if(is_file('way_to_a_file.php'){
        require_once('way_to_a_file.php');
        return $my_content;
    }
}

add_shortcode('my_function', 'myfunction')
```

Comment: Thanks, if have yet tried to put return . The problem is always here. the file exist and is functioning, I have no error on the website online, and the php make its work. Maybe i can put a condition for the case where elementor is on edition mode but i don't know how to make it.

Comment: Tks again @Vski, the editor crashes because it didn't found the file, whereas it was well found when the page is viewed by a visitor..;